# Dual Boot not recognizing new hard drive

Tags: dual-boot

I am a complete Linux newb..which will become obvious shortly.

The story:
I wanted to dual boot with Ubuntu.  I already had windows on 1 hard drive (320gb), and I wanted Ubuntu on a 2nd hard drive (2tb).  I setup the partitions using the "Something else" option - I left the first hard drive alone, and put a swap and a ext4 partition on the 2nd hard drive.  When it asked me where the bootable device was, I put the first hard drive.

The problem:
Now that Ubuntu is installed and grub lets me pick which os to boot to, I boot to Ubuntu JUST FINE.  BUT when I go to the home folder and look at devices, the only drive showing is the 320 gb/old hard drive that windows was installed on.  I can not see the 2 TB hard drive anywhere.  This is strange because I setup the Ubuntu partition to be the 2 TB hard drive and I thought I installed Ubuntu on that partition.

Thank you for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, there is nothing wrong with your installation. It is exactly the way Nautilus is **supposed to** display your file system.

The 320 GB drive represents another drive **in addition** to your Ubuntu drive. This drive can be mounted by clicking on it (but it may not be mounted by default). In addition to this drive only the mounted filesystem on your 2nd hard drive is shown (represented as folders).

To view all drives (`/sda /sdb /sdc ...`) and partitions (`/sda1 /sda2 ... /sdb1 /sdb2 ...`) in your system you may issue the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This is how Nautilus displays my system of 4 drives:

[image]

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH haha I understand now.  So it only shows the "additional" drives under devices.  Awesome! Thank you for the quick response!  And I do see the all drives/partitions when using fdisk!  THANK YOU!

Comment: yeah, that is a bit different to what you may have been used to.

Comment: It does take a bit getting used to but so far I am really enjoying this OS.  I can't believe that it found drivers for my audio interface and that installing drivers for my graphics card was so easy!  Thanks again for helping out a complete newb (just started today!)